# Asking a question related to greatest integer function in number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This question was asked in a quiz for my course in Elementary number theory today and I am unable to think at the moment how to solve this question.

> **Question:** By using Greatest Integer Function , show that  $n!(n-1)!$ divides $(2n-2)!$.

I can think only that $n+n-1 >2n-2$ so dividing by $p^k$ , where $p$ is any prime and summing $k$ from $1$ to $\infty$ we get the opposite of what is asked and if both inclusions hold then both $n! (n-1)! = (2n-2)!$ Which is clearly not true. So, I think the question is wrong.

Am I right? 
Can you please verify.

Comment: **Hints:** (1) [This](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/De_Polignac%27s_Formula), (2) $\gcd(n,n-1)=1$.

Comment: @user170039 can you please tell what's wrong in my argument?

Comment: @user170039 applying de polignac formula implies the opposite of what is asked in question

Comment: Your argument doesn't appear to make any sense.  What difference does it make that $n+n-1>2n-2$?   After all, $2+2>3$ but, taking the prime $p=3$,  $3\nmid 2!\times 2!$

Comment: @lulu I am asking can it be proved that [ $\frac{n } {p^k} $ )] + [ $\frac{n-1} {p^k} $] >  [ $\frac{2n-2} {p^k} $ ]  not what you wrote!!

Comment: @user170039  can it be proved that [ $\frac{n } {p^k} $ )] + [ $\frac{n-1} {p^k} $] >  [ $\frac{2n-2} {p^k} $ ]  ?

Comment: Once again, the argument you wrote makes no apparent sense.  Perhaps if you added more detail.  Alternatively, check your computation for particular choices of $n, p, k$.  The desired claim is easily verified for particular values of $n$, for instance.

Comment: @user170039  Not sure I am following your argument either. the fact that $p\,\nmid n$, say certainly does not imply that, say, $\big \lfloor \frac np\big \rfloor=0$.

Comment: @lulu: Yep. I was about to note that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a straight forward way to do it via the greatest integer function, but for a quick proof:

We have $$\frac {(2n-2)!}{n!(n-1)!}=\frac 1{n}\times \binom {2n-2}{n-1}=C_{n-1}$$

So the claim follows by the usual properties of the [Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

Comment: but it is to be proved that n!  × (n-1)! divides (2n-2)! not (2n-1)! and also Right side of equality is not equl to left side of equality!!

Comment: Yes, there's a typo, I will correct it.

Comment: sorry but I can't accept it. I am looking for a proof using Greatest integer function.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $n$.  We want to show that, for all primes $p$, the power of $p$ in $\frac{(2n-2)!}{n!\,(n-1)!}$ is non-negative.

Fix $p$.  The power of $p$ in each of the three factorials can be found from the de Polignac formula, which is a formula that, for a non-negative integer $a$, gives $\mu(a)$, the highest power of $p$ dividing $a!$:
$$
\mu(a)=\sum_{k>0}\left\lfloor\frac{a}{p^k}\right\rfloor.
$$

Let $\ell$ be the largest exponent such that $p^\ell$ divides $n$.  From the formula we get
$$
\mu(n)=\mu(n-1)+\ell,
$$
which implies that the power of $p$ dividing our denominator, $n!\,(n-1)!$, is $2\mu(n-1)+\ell$.

For the numerator, it is clear that $\left\lfloor\frac{2n-2}{p^k}\right\rfloor\ge2\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{p^k}\right\rfloor$, with equality holding precisely when the fractional part of $\frac{n-1}{p^k}$ is less than $\frac{1}{2}$.  For $1\le k\le\ell$ the expression $\frac{n}{p^k}$ is an integer, and, since $p\ge2$, the fractional part of $\frac{n-1}{p^k}=\frac{n}{p^k}-\frac{1}{p^k}$ is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.  It follows that $\mu(2n-1)\ge2\mu(n-1)+\ell$.

***Example:*** Let $n=5$.  Take the primes one at a time.

For $p=2$ we have $\ell=0$ and $\mu(5)=\mu(4)=2+1=3$.  But $\mu(8)=4+2+1=7>2\cdot3$.

For $p=3$ we have $\ell=0$ and $\mu(5)=\mu(4)=1$.  And $\mu(8)=2=2\cdot1$.

For $p=5$ we have $\ell=1$ and $\mu(5)=\mu(4)+1=0+1=1$.  And $\mu(8)=1=2\cdot0+1$.

For $p=7$ we have $\ell=0$ and $\mu(5)=\mu(4)=0$.  But $\mu(8)=1>2\cdot0$.

For $p\ge11$ we have $\ell=0$ and $\mu(5)=\mu(4)=\mu(8)=0$.

Finally $\frac{8!}{5!\,4!}=14=2\cdot7$.  Note that $2$ and $7$ were the two primes for which $\mu(8)$ exceeded $2\mu(4)+\ell$.